# Can `dig` show me all common record types at once?

Tags: dns, dig

Is there a way to have `dig` request (potentially over several requests) all of the common types of records for a domain at once? `dig any domain.com` and `dig all domain.com` seem to be lacking... everything.

E.g. I would like output that includes `mx`, `txt`, `a`, `aaaa`, `ns`, `ptr`, etc. all at once. Is that possible with `dig`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is lacking from the output of, say, `dig example.com any`?

Comment: @JimL. the DNS server isn't obligated to respond with all records, such as `txt`, `mx`, etc. When a record might be returned with `mx` when explicitly asked, `any` doesn't have to return such records. I want `dig` to run a query for each record type and return all of the results...

Comment: @Qix. `dig` does not currently have the ability to do what you are looking for.

Comment: @fpmurphy I figured not; if you make an answer stating that, I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Lets suppose there is a software which just sends multiple requests with the most commonly used record types (maybe 5-10) and displays the results conveniently to the user. How would this software be called?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you want to use the AXFR query type. For example:

```
dig AXFR yourdomain.com @DNS.server.fqdn
```

Do keep in mind that many domains do not permit zone transfer queries from unknown sources, so you may get no response or an empty response.

Edit: The AXFR is the only way to get all record types in one query. If you don't want to use an AXFR, you have to issue queries for each record type you're interested in. For example:

```
for f in A MX CNAME
do
  dig $f your.domain.name @DNS.server.FQDN
done
```

There is no list of "most common" record types. You must supply that list yourself. IMHO, this is a nonsensical use case, as the two most common record types by likelihood of encountering them are A and PTR record, and there's absolutely no way to get both record types in a single query. You'll see A and CNAME records returned at the same time, but rarely will you see any other query with more than one type of record returned.

Bottom line - AXFR is the answer you actually want for the question you asked. Whether you believe that or not is another matter entirely.

Comment: I don't want a zone transfer query. I want `dig` to simply run `dig mx ...`, `dig a ...`, `dig txt ...`, etc. all at once.

Comment: @JohnHanley because a zone transfer request is not what I asked for. Very simple. I also realize that DNS supports any number of record types. I'm asking for the most common ones, even if it must make several requests. If `dig` doesn't support this, simply say so.

Comment: @JohnHanley what makes you think I hadn't done my own research? I commented before they edited their answer, by the way. Why are you getting upset? Also to the answerer, I don't see why this is a "nonsensical" question to ask.

Comment: I believe I preemptively answered why this is a nonsensical use case in my edit. After checking my notes - yes I did.

Comment: @JohnHanley you intentionally misinterpreting my question is not grounds for you dismissing it. What a nightmare StackExchange has become.